# Spring MVC - Ajax call returns JSON with Unterminated string

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm very new to this, like really, really new.
I'm using Spring MVC (5.0) and am making an ajax call, as shown below.
This all works fine.

```
@RestController
public class AjaxController
{
   @RequestMapping(value="/search/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public Person getUsers(@RequestParam("username") String username)
   {
      persons = personService.findPersonByUsername(username);

      return persons.size() == 0 ? null : persons.get(0);
   }
}
```

The method gets the person from the database and returns it.
According to the Spring Restful guide,

"The XXX object must be converted to JSON.Thanks to Spring’s HTTP message converter support, you don’t need to do this conversion manually. Because Jackson 2 is on the classpath, Spring’s MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is automatically chosen to convert the XXX instance to JSON."

So, Spring is automatically generating the JSON which will be returned to the client.  The problem is, I get an error message in my client javascript:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string literal at line 1 column 103911 of the JSON data

My client javascript is equally simple, consisting of only:

```
function ajax_get_users(input_box)
{
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhttp.open("GET", "users?username=" + username, true);                         // url of server-side ajax script, specify synchronous ajax call
                                                                                  // get asynchronous response
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()     {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var person = JSON.parse(this.responseText);                               // this is where the unterminated String error occurs
     }
   };

   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   // set http header
   xhttp.send();                                                                  // send the ajax request to the web server
}
```

Since Spring is constructing the JSON, how do I even fix the problem?

Comment: Most likely, your `Person` object contains some special characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Did you `curl` against the service and had a look what the response is already? Also the column 103911 looks very suspicious, probably response is truncated?